# A div in absolute position outside the body

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

I want to see only the half of my div at the end of my page. 
I tried to apply a `bottom:-100px` or `margin-bottom:-100px` or `padding-bottom:-100px`, but nothing works.

What can I do?

**Here's my JSFIDDLE : https://jsfiddle.net/cuxyrfh8/6/**

```
div {
  background: pink;
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  right: 0;
  width: 400px;
  border: 5px black solid;
  bottom:-100px;
}
```

Comment: What about it doesn't work? Looks like it's 100px below the bottom of the page to me.

Comment: Already given code represents the same.. Then what do you require

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `div` is exactly 100px outside of the viewport. I assume you don't want that scrolling behaviour? You can achieve that width `overflow: hidden;`.

**Edit 1**:
If the body's height is greater than the viewport, you can set `position: relative;` so that the div's position is orientated on the body.

**Edit 2**:
If you want the halve div on a down scrolled body, you need a wrapper element and apply the overflow and position rules to it.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper div {
  background: pink;
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  right: 0;
  width: 400px;
  border: 5px black solid;
  bottom:-100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated my jsfiddle. If my body have a 1000px of height, I want my div be at the end of the body

Comment: Ok, the div is now at the end of my page, but we still view the full div, and i want to see only the half of my div...

Comment: Then you have to use `position: relative;` for a wrapper. I've updated my answere.

Answer (score 1):

Negative Paddings do **not** work at all. Make use of a wrapper element:

### HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="thediv">
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.wrapper {
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.thediv {
    background: pink;
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    right: 0;
    width: 400px;
    border: 5px black solid;
    top: 0;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ng8g1uor/2/)**

Comment: It doesn't work if your body have a " height:2000px ".

Comment: Simply because you shouldnt do that, the only appropriate height you should give a body is `height: 100%`

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve what you wish by changing the `position` of the element from `aboslute` to `fixed`, like so:

```css
div{
    background:pink;
    border:5px black solid;
    bottom:-100px;
    height:200px;
    left:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    width:400px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I do not want to have a fixed position, but an absolute.

Answer (score 0):

`bottom: -100px` would move the div to the bottom by 100px, and so scrollbar will appear (full div will be visible).

To avoid that use `overflow: hidden` on the `body` of the page.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
div {
  background: pink;
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 5px black solid;
  bottom: -100px;
}
div:hover {
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```